# Magento2 display header compare link after custom block in header

Tags: magento2, compare

Magento2 move header compare link after custom block in the header

I have added custom block in header as follows

```
<referenceContainer name="header.topcontent">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Blockname" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="home_page_top_content_block" xsi:type="string">home_page_top_content_block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

I need to display this block **catalog.compare.link** after my custom block

Answer (score 0):

```
<move element="catalog.compare.link" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content"/>
```

Might help someone

Answer (score 0):

you have to override default.xml in your theme.

> app/design/frontend/{{YOUR THEME NAME
> HERE}}/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

We have created one example of how to move compare link after custom block.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="blockname" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">home_page_top_content_block</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    <move element="catalog.compare.link" destination="page.top" before="home_page_top_content_block"/>
</page>
```

After that add the below CSS in your custom CSS or less.

```
.page-wrapper .item.link.compare .no-display {
    display: block;
}
```

Please check and let us know if you still facing any issues.